# Ping fails since arp request is getting sent over wired interface when expected to be sent over wireless interface

Tags: android, linux, networking

I have a STB device (reference board) having Android-M with Linux kernel 3.14.28-1.9pre.

```
On this board, I have 2 network interfaces:

    gphy: Wired Interface (10.131.24.211)
    wlan0: Wireless Interface (192.168.1.3)

On STB, using wireless interface i associated to an AP on channel 6. Thereafter I try to ping to AP (192.168.1.1). But ping fails.
```

**Ping Results:**

```
 root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # ping 192.168.1.1                  
    PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    ^C
    --- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms
```

On another terminal, tcpdump for wired interface (gphy) shows that arp request is sent from wired interface for address 10.131.24.1 and ARP reply also came for wired interface. But when I tried tcpdump on wireless interface, no arp request/response were seen.

**tcpdump results:**

```
130|root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # tcpdump -nni gphy arp
[ 2938.268561] device gphy entered promiscuous mode
[ 2938.273205] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on gphy, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:51:20.047056 ARP, Request who-has 10.131.24.1 tell 10.131.24.211, length 28
13:51:20.048108 ARP, Reply 10.131.24.1 is-at 00:00:0c:07:ac:18, length 46
13:50:50.047057 ARP, Request who-has 10.131.24.1 tell 10.131.24.211, length 28
13:50:50.048132 ARP, Reply 10.131.24.1 is-at 00:00:0c:07:ac:18, length 46

On checking the arp entries, there were only 2 entries related to wired interface. First wired entry was for wired interface and second entry was for adb connection from host machine (10.131.24.203) through wired interface. There was no entry added for wireless interface.
```

**arp results:**

```
root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # /system/xbin/busybox arp          
? (10.131.24.1) at 00:00:0c:07:ac:18 [ether]  on gphy
? (10.131.24.203) at d4:be:d9:6a:f8:77 [ether]  on gphy

If i ping by specifying wireless interface name (wlan0) this worked fine.
```

**ping results:**

```
root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # ping -I wlan0 192.168.1.1    
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=72.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=8.25 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=9.12 ms

On another terminal the tcpdump on wireless interface for arp packets clearly shows arp request for 192.168.1.1 and arp reply.
```

**tcpdump results:**

```
130|root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # tcpdump -nni wlan0 arp        
[ 3191.490560] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:54:58.395951 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.3 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
13:54:58.396032 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.3 is-at 00:90:4c:a5:12:38, length 28

Now again i checked the arp entries and found that an entry for wireless interface (wlan0) is created and added.
```

**arp results:**

```
130|root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # /system/xbin/busybox arp      
? (192.168.1.1) at 00:90:4c:0f:f1:47 [ether]  on wlan0
? (10.131.24.203) at d4:be:d9:6a:f8:77 [ether]  on gphy
? (10.131.24.1) at 00:00:0c:07:ac:18 [ether]  on gphy

From this analysis, it is observed that arp requests are being sent on wired interface and for wired ip address even though arp is requested for wireless interface on wireless interface.

If I disable the wired interface, ping work fine.
```

**ping results:**

```
1|root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # ifconfig gphy down

1|root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # ping 192.168.1.1       
64 bytes from 192.168.1.3 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=72.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=8.25 ms
```

arp table shows entry for 192.168.1.1

```
Below are the route table details.
```

**route results:**

```
root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # route 
Kernel IP routing table Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface default 10.131.24.1 0.0.0.0 UG 204 0 0 gphy 
10.131.24.0 * 255.255.254.0 U 204 0 0 gphy 
192.168.1.0 * 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 wlan0
```

Below is the result of ip route get 192.168.1.1.

```
root@bcm_platform:/system/bin/amar/43242a1 # ip route get 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1 via 10.131.24.1 dev gphy src 10.131.24.211 uid 0 cache 

This clearly shows that the route for wireless ip address is via wired interface. Since the Access point is not connected via wired interface, it cannot be reached.

Could someone please provide solution for this problem?

Regards, Amar
```